# How to login to shutterstock through python?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, oauth-2.0, shutterstock

I have a Windows10 + Python3.7

Right now i using requests for download web content and analyse it. But i can change it to selenium or something else if it needed...

I Want to login to shutterstock website through python to get some information from user pages (my sales data and etc). Shutterstock don't have any API for this actions and for many actions too... I want to write a console script for collecting data only. I will saving data to CSV file

I can parse my page to find all what i'm interested, but before it i'm need to login. And here is a problem because site have a login page with google "I'm not a robot" widget.

I tried to use requests auth functions - but it's doesn't working.

This is a login page:
https://contributor-accounts.shutterstock.com/login

Site don't have any tokens and other auth items. I saw software who connect to shutterstock. It just show popup window with all of this items from login page and then starting work without any windows.

My questions:

- How to login to shutterstock?
- How to store session for a long time if it possible, because i want to run my script every 4 hours and don't want to see login window every time

Comment: Are you sure the software you saw connecting with shutterstock doesn't require REST API hidden behind paywall? https://developers.shutterstock.com/. 
Because captcha purpose is exactly to block this kind of connection.

Comment: yes i'm sure. because all API in shutterstock only for downloading images and nothing more. for contributor stuff this site don't have any solutions and APIs

Comment: @MaxKu have you had any development of this situation? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Shutterstock is working on building out a contributor api that would allow contributors to programmatically fetch their earnings and downloads data. These specific endpoints are still in progress, plan is to get them out early next year. If you reach out to contributor support they can probably add you as a beta user for these (and other) features that you're looking for.

Comment: i'm talked with a support year ago. and support told me the same. and now i can't wait anymore. maybe after 10 years it will be done - in this case i'll switch to API. but now i need solution and API not ready yet